# How to convert latitude and longitude in DMS format into decimal format (and vice versa)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, latitude-longitude, converters

Does python contain any library to convert latitude and longitude in DMS format into decimal format and vice versa?

Comment: I doubt something like that is in the standard library ...

Comment: He didn't ask about the standard library. This is the library he asked for: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/LatLon/1.0.2

Comment: It's a valid question and has a valid answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

#example for : 0°25'30"S, 91°7'W

def conversion(old):
    direction = {'N':-1, 'S':1, 'E': -1, 'W':1}
    new = old.replace(u'°',' ').replace('\'',' ').replace('"',' ')
    new = new.split()
    new_dir = new.pop()
    new.extend([0,0,0])
    return (int(new[0])+int(new[1])/60.0+int(new[2])/3600.0) * direction[new_dir]

lat, lon = u'''0°25'30"S, 91°7'W'''.split(', ')
print conversion(lat), conversion(lon)
#Output:
0.425 91.1166666667
```

from : [Python - Batch convert GPS positions to Lat Lon decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852955/python-batch-convert-gps-positions-to-lat-lon-decimals)

and for the other way :

```
def deg_to_dms(deg):
    d = int(deg)
    md = abs(deg - d) * 60
    m = int(md)
    sd = (md - m) * 60
    return [d, m, sd]

#output
>>> deg_to_dms(91.1166666667)
[91, 7, 1.199953203467885e-07]
>>> deg_to_dms(0.425)
[0, 25, 30.0]
```

from : [Lat Long to Minutes and Seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056750/lat-long-to-minutes-and-seconds)