# latitude and longitude format conversion

Tags: python, geolocation, geocoding, latitude-longitude

Could anyone help me on how to convert the below latitude and logitude cordinate completely to float.
for example, i want to convert from this format  "30.4719° N, 91.1013°E" to something like "34.565656,91.454545".i have a lot of record to convert from this format. if anyone could help me with the formula it will be really helpfull.
thank you.

Comment: How does `30.4719` map to `34.565656`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert latitude longitude to decimal in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298772/how-to-convert-latitude-longitude-to-decimal-in-python)