# Converting pandas data frame with degree minute second (DMS) coordinates to decimal degrees

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I have a `data frame` like the below and would like to convert the `Latitude` and `Longitude` columns in Degree, Minute, Second format into decimal degrees - with negative for the correct hemisphere. Is there an easy way to do that?

```
Parent Company  CPO PKO Latitude    Longitude
Incasi Raya X       0°51'56.29"S    101°26'46.29"E
Incasi Raya X       1°23'39.29"S    101°35'30.45"E
Incasi Raya X       0°19'56.63"N    99°22'56.36"E
Incasi Raya X       0°21'45.91"N    99°37'59.68"E
Incasi Raya X       1°41'6.56"S 102°14'7.68"E
Incasi Raya X       1°15'2.13"S 101°34'30.38"E
Incasi Raya X       2°19'44.26"S    100°59'34.55"E
Musim Mas   X       1°44'55.94"N    101°22'15.94"E
```

For example `0°51'56.29"S` would be converted to `-0.8656361`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852955/python-batch-convert-gps-positions-to-lat-lon-decimals and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997361/how-to-convert-degree-minute-second-to-degree-decimal-in-python

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basing my answer on a function from SO you can do it like this:

Interestingly this answer is also 2x as fast as MaxU and Amis answer for a dataset with +500 rows. My bet is that the bottleneck is str.extract(). But something is clearly strange.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997361
def dms2dd(s):
    # example: s = """0°51'56.29"S"""
    degrees, minutes, seconds, direction = re.split('[°\'"]+', s)
    dd = float(degrees) + float(minutes)/60 + float(seconds)/(60*60);
    if direction in ('S','W'):
        dd*= -1
    return dd

df = pd.DataFrame({'CPO': {0: 'Raya', 1: 'Raya'},
 'Latitude': {0: '0°51\'56.29"S', 1: '1°23\'39.29"S'},
 'Longitude': {0: '101°26\'46.29"E', 1: '101°35\'30.45"E'},
 'PKO': {0: 'X', 1: 'X'},
 'ParentCompany': {0: 'Incasi', 1: 'Incasi'}})

df['Latitude'] = df['Latitude'].apply(dms2dd)
df['Longitude'] = df['Longitude'].apply(dms2dd)
```

printing df returns:

```
    CPO   Latitude   Longitude PKO ParentCompany
0  Raya  -0.865636  101.446192   X        Incasi
1  Raya  -1.394247  101.591792   X        Incasi
```

---

**Update:** To correct your mistake you could do something in the lines of:

```
m = df['Latitude'].str[-2] != '"'
df.loc[m, 'Latitude'] = df.loc[m, 'Latitude'].str[:-1] + '"' + df.loc[m, 'Latitude'].str[-1]
```

Full example:

```
import re

s1 = """0°51'56.29"S"""
s2 = """0°51'56.29S"""

df = pd.Series((s1,s2)).to_frame(name='Latitude')

m = df['Latitude'].str[-2] != '"'
df.loc[m, 'Latitude'] = df.loc[m, 'Latitude'].str[:-1] + '"' + df.loc[m, 'Latitude'].str[-1]

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, @Anton vBR. It worked great on the `Longitude` column but for some weird reason I am getting this - `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)` when I run it on my `Latitude` column. Any idea why that could be happening?

Comment: Ok, just realised one row had a value like this `0°45'2.22S` instead of `0°45'2.22"S` so I guess that must have caused it. Is there any easy way to get around this?

Comment: @Funkeh-Monkeh Is it only one row? I'd manually go in and change it to the correct value in that case. In other case, if you are sure everything else is correct I added an updated code you could run before you apply the functions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use vectorized operations using [`pd.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html). For the latitude, for example:

```
parts = df.Latitude.str.extract('(\d+)°(\d+)\'([^"]+)"([N|S|E|W])', expand=True)
>>> (parts[0].astype(int) + parts[1].astype(float) / 60 + parts[2].astype(float) / 3600) * parts[3].map({'N':1, 'S':-1, 'E': 1, 'W':-1})
0    101.446192
1    101.591792
2     99.382322
3     99.633244
4    102.235467
5    101.575106
6    100.992931
7    101.371094
```

Comment: funny, i had very similar idea ;-)

Comment: I have got a large serie including some NaN (empty) values. How can I skip that values and use pd.series.str.extract ?

Comment: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized approach, that also uses `matrix` * `vector` (`[1, 1./60, 1./3600]`) multiplication:

```
In [233]: %paste
def dms2dec(s):
    x = (s.str.upper()
          .str.split(r'[°\'"]', expand=True)
          .replace(['S','W','N','E'], [-1,-1,1,1])
          .astype('float'))
    return x.iloc[:, :3].dot([1, 1./60, 1./3600]).mul(x.iloc[:, 3])

## -- End pasted text --

In [234]: df[['Latitude','Longitude']] = df[['Latitude','Longitude']].apply(dms2dec)

In [235]: df
Out[235]:
  Parent Company CPO PKO  Latitude   Longitude
0    Incasi Raya       X -0.865636  101.446192
1    Incasi Raya       X -1.394247  101.591792
2    Incasi Raya       X  0.332397   99.382322
3    Incasi Raya       X  0.362753   99.633244
4    Incasi Raya       X -1.685156  102.235467
5    Incasi Raya       X -1.250592  101.575106
6    Incasi Raya       X -2.328961  100.992931
7      Musim Mas       X  1.748872  101.371094
```

step by step explanation:

```
In [239]: x = (s.str.upper()
     ...:       .str.split(r'[°\'"]', expand=True)
     ...:       .replace(['S','W','N','E'], [-1,-1,1,1])
     ...:       .astype('float'))

In [240]: x
Out[240]:
     0     1      2    3
0  0.0  51.0  56.29 -1.0
1  1.0  23.0  39.29 -1.0
2  0.0  19.0  56.63  1.0
3  0.0  21.0  45.91  1.0
4  1.0  41.0   6.56 -1.0
5  1.0  15.0   2.13 -1.0
6  2.0  19.0  44.26 -1.0
7  1.0  44.0  55.94  1.0

In [241]: x.iloc[:, :3].dot([1, 1./60, 1./3600])
Out[241]:
0    0.865636
1    1.394247
2    0.332397
3    0.362753
4    1.685156
5    1.250592
6    2.328961
7    1.748872
dtype: float64

In [242]: x.iloc[:, :3].dot([1, 1./60, 1./3600]).mul(x.iloc[:, 3])
Out[242]:
0   -0.865636
1   -1.394247
2    0.332397
3    0.362753
4   -1.685156
5   -1.250592
6   -2.328961
7    1.748872
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I don't get it. For some reason your solution runs 10 times slower than mine when timing.

Comment: @AntonvBR, what is the length of your test DF?

Comment: Small, only 2 rows .. but should it really matter? What is slowing it down for the small sample? I removed the overhead and your function takes 33ms while "mine" takes 1 ms.

Comment: @AntonvBR, yes it does matter. That's interesting, your solution seems to be approx. 2x faster compared to mine (for larger DFs)...

Comment: Yeah, I mean I understand it matters. But I mean it shouldnt be a factor 33 for a small set still. I'm gonna look at Amis answer

Comment: Ok, Ami's answer is also slower. Can it be str.extract constructing a dataset that takes time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`clean_lat_long()`](https://docs.dataprep.ai/user_guide/clean/clean_lat_long.html) from the library [DataPrep](https://dataprep.ai/). Install it with `pip install dataprep`.

```py
from dataprep.clean import clean_lat_long
df = pd.DataFrame({"Latitude": ["0°51'56.29''S", "1°23'39.29''S", "0°19'56.63''N"],
     "Longitude": ["101°26'46.29''E", "101°35'30.45''E", "99°22'56.36''E"]})

df2 = clean_lat_long(df, lat_col="Latitude", long_col="Longitude", split=True)
df2
        Latitude        Longitude  Latitude_clean  Longitude_clean
0  0°51'56.29''S  101°26'46.29''E         -0.8656         101.4462
1  1°23'39.29''S  101°35'30.45''E         -1.3942         101.5918
2  0°19'56.63''N   99°22'56.36''E          0.3324          99.3823
```