# Split in Python regex with symbol and uppercase letter

Tags: python, python-re

In the spirit of this questions: [Converting pandas data frame with degree minute second (DMS) coordinates to decimal degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193159/converting-pandas-data-frame-with-degree-minute-second-dms-coordinates-to-deci?noredirect=1&lq=1) I want to convert a longitude with the format, for instance, 18-23-34W to a decimal, i.e., -18.392778. I want to separate by the minus, -, and by uppercase.

The function in the link I have been trying, adapted to my necessities:

```
def dms2dd(s):
    degrees, minutes, seconds, direction = re.split('[A-Z-]+', s)
    dd = float(degrees) + float(minutes) / 60 + float(seconds) / (60 * 60)
    if direction in ('S', 'W'):
        dd *= -1
    return dd
```

The problem seems to be with the regex in `degrees, minutes, seconds, direction = re.split('[A-Z-]+', s)`. I obtain the conversion but not the multiplication by -1, as it should be. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `seconds` would give you `'34'` - because you "remove" the `W`: splitting-characters are never kept.

Potential fix:

```
import re

def dms2dd(s):
    degrees, minutes, seconds, *_ = re.split('[A-Z-]+', s)
    direction = s[-1]

    dd = float(degrees) + float(minutes)/60 + float(seconds)/(60*60)
    if direction in ('S','W'):
        dd*= -1
    return dd


print(dms2dd("18-23-34W"))  # -18.392777777777777  - add a round(_,6) to get yours
```