# Reading coordinates in python in form longitude: 5°20'56" latitude E 46°05'58"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, coordinates

I wanna do a scatter plot of stations on a map of which I have the stations coordinates in aforementioned format.

Is there a possibility to read or transform the above described type of coordinates with pandas ?
Or do I have to transform them myself in the more common form  latitude: 47.8410 longitude: 8.8490

Thanks in advance :)

I searched for transformation possibilities but of all examples I found the coordinates where already given in the more common form [Dataframe and given coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igFCZ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Roxy, I added a screenshot of the first rows of the dataframe. I'd like to plat for example the 6 min precipitation column, but it seems not possible in the given format of the coordinates...

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193328/2836621